# The constructor FragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager) is undefined

Tags: android

I can't figure out what is going on with the constructor for the tabs Adapter.

```
 public TabsAdapter(Activity activity, ViewPager pager) {
         super(activity.getSupportFragmentManager());
```

This is giving me the error message: `The method getSupportFragmentManager() is undefined for the type Activity`

I think I am using the correct imports.  Below is the code that is pretty much copied straight from Android at this point.

```
 import android.app.ActionBar;
 import android.app.ActionBar.Tab;
 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
 import android.content.Context;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
 import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
 import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
 import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
 import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener;

public class TabsAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter
     implements ActionBar.TabListener, ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {

     private final Context mContext;
     private final ActionBar mActionBar;
     private final ViewPager mViewPager;
     private final ArrayList<TabInfo> mTabs = new ArrayList<TabInfo>();


     static final class TabInfo {

         private final Class<?> clss;
         private final Bundle args;

        TabInfo(Class<?> _class, Bundle _args) {
           clss = _class;
           args = _args;
        }
}

public TabsAdapter(Activity activity, ViewPager pager) {
    super(activity.getSupportFragmentManager());


    mContext = activity;
    mActionBar = activity.getActionBar();
    mViewPager = pager;
    mViewPager.setAdapter(this);
    mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);
}

public void addTab(ActionBar.Tab tab, Class<?> clss, Bundle args) {

    TabInfo info = new TabInfo(clss, args);
    tab.setTag(info);
    tab.setTabListener(this);
    mTabs.add(info);
    mActionBar.addTab(tab);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public int getCount() {

    return mTabs.size();
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {

    TabInfo info = mTabs.get(position);
    return Fragment.instantiate(mContext, info.clss.getName(), info.args);
}

@Override
public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

}

@Override
public void onPageSelected(int position) {

    mActionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
}

@Override
public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {


}
@Override
public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    Object tag = tab.getTag();
    for (int i=0; i<mTabs.size(); i++) {
        if (mTabs.get(i) == tag) {
            mViewPager.setCurrentItem(i);
        }
    }

}

 }
```

Thanks to anyone taking a look at this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
import android.app.Activity;
```

to

```
android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity
```

you must use support library.

Comment: Thanks!  This got me going in the right direction.  I had to extend `FragmentActivity` instead of `Activity` and of course pass it a `FragmentActivity` but it is working now. Oh, I also had to remove the `setContentView` method in the Activity which I forgot to do when creating the Activity.