# Error in imports of eclipse - developing android

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I think I'm having troubles with Eclipse's imports, but I haven't been able to pinpoint the problem. I'm trying to implement a `FragmentPagerAdapter` but I'm getting the "The constructor FragmentPageAdapter(FragmentManager) is undefined". There's the exact same question here in SO at "[The constructor FragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager) is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27209876/the-constructor-fragmentpageradapterfragmentmanager-is-undefined)" but the answer in that post didn't work for me.

Any suggestions? thanks in advance! :)

(the offending line is `super(act.getFragmentManager());`)

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class MainFragmentsPager_Adapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter{
    ArrayList<ViewGroup> views = new ArrayList<ViewGroup>();


//  public MainFragmentsPager_Adapter(FragmentManager fm) {
//      super(fm);
//  }

    public MainFragmentsPager_Adapter(FragmentActivity act, Context context) {
        super(act.getFragmentManager());
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View x = inflater.inflate(R.id.fragment_noticias, null);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `act.getSupportFragmentManager()` instead.

This should fix your problem as you  are using support library.

Cheers.